# How can I retrieve an attachment in a Cloudant database with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, https, ibm-cloud, indy, cloudant

I have successfully created a Bluemix Cloudant document and did Put an attachment to that doc with a Delphi program. I'm also able to retrieve that attachment via a BAT-file, but I should like to do it with Delphi 2009. I get 
a HTTP/1.1 200 OK response, I don't know where to get the attachment
The code:

```
  program httpsGet;

  {$R *.res}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

  uses
    IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdGlobal, SysUtils,IniFiles, Classes;

  var
    HTTP: TIdHTTP;
    RequestBody: TStream;
    ResponseBody: string;
    LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    json: string;
    F:  textfile;
    s:  string;
    id,rev: string;
    Dir,user,password,mapp,butik: string;
    IniFile:  TInifile;
    a,i,x,Antdocs:  integer;
  begin
  //  Read ini-file and get user / password
    Dir:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
    IniFile:=TIniFile.create(Dir + 'Credentials.ini');
    user:=IniFile.Readstring('Credentials','User','');
    password:=IniFile.Readstring('Credentials','Password','');
    IniFile.Destroy;

    id:='02d42fc7c5966b2ab7d27a3c9942a77e';
    rev:='2-904b6ca2f8883e35b931d138acc969c6';
    json:='{ "selector": {"_id":"' + id + '"}, "fields": "_attachment" } ';

    HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      try
        RequestBody := TStringStream.Create(json, TEncoding.UTF8);
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

        try
          WriteLn(' RequestBody: ' + json);
          WriteLn('');
          HTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
          HTTP.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
          HTTP.Request.UserName := user;
          HTTP.Request.Password := password;
          HTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
          HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
          HTTP.IOHandler:=LHandler;
          ResponseBody := HTTP.Get('https://' + user + '.cloudant.com/pmu/');
          WriteLn(' ResponseBody: ' + ResponseBody);
          WriteLn(HTTP.ResponseText);
        finally
          RequestBody.Free;
          Lhandler.Free;
        end;
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        begin
          WriteLn(E.Message);
          WriteLn(E.ErrorMessage);
        end;
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          WriteLn(E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      HTTP.Free;
    end;

    ReadLn;
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  end.
```

Output is:

> RequestBody: { "selector": {"_id":"02d42fc7c5966b2ab7d27a3c9942a77e"},
>   "fields": "_attachment" } ResponseBody:
>   {"update_seq":"331-g1AAAAPHeJzLYWBgEMhgTmFQSUlKzi9KdUhJMjTQS8rVTU7WLc3WNTDUS87JL01JzCvRy0styQGqZkpkSOL___9_ViIHSJ8yQh9-bUkCQDJJHqxTAFWnGQGdCiCd-mCdoqg6jQjoNADptAfr5CTNl0kOIK3-YK3iqJZaEtAZANIZD9YpSZpHE0A688E6hUjzaAFIZz1YJz9pHs1jAZIMDUAKqLsfI4QJeBaiewJE9_ysRHlU3ebE6F4A0b0-K1GaJE9DdG-A6N6flahIjscPQLSfJzWWIbovQHTfJzWmIbofQHS_z0rkJcPjHyC6QekzCwCYMTXF","db_name":"pmu","sizes":{"file":9239940,"external":2290914,"active":2392413},"purge_seq":0,"other":{"data_size":2290914},"doc_del_count":130,"doc_count":2,"disk_size":9239940,"disk_format_version":6,"data_size":2392413,"compact_running":false,"instance_start_time":"0"}
>   HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I have expected the attachment to be the ResponseBody.
The Cloudant doc looks as follows:
[Doc layout for specified id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk4ym.png)

Can anybody give me a hint?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're not hitting the right URL.

Two issues as I can see: you're trying to use Cloudant Query, given how you've constructed your json payload. It needs to be a POST on the `/$DATABASE/_find` endpoint, whereas you're issuing a GET on just `/$DATABASE`. See

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#finding-documents-by-using-an-index

Secondly, there are two ways by which attachments are stored in Cloudant, either as a separate blob, or as inline content. Access to attachments depends on which flavour you're using.

See

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/attachments.html#attachments

for more details.